Credientials error when importing .net users into Firebase
I am trying to import users from my DNN site into Firebase using the aspnet_Membership provider. To do this, I have written a script in F# (C# is fine, too) to retrieve the user details from the aspnet_Membership table, including the Password and Password Salt.
The users are imported, but I have a credentials error when I try to sign in.  I assume this has something to do with the password. From the web.config I have:
<machineKey validationKey="<validationKey>" decryptionKey="<decryptionKey>" decryption="3DES" validation="SHA1" />

And this is the key elements of the code I am using.
let passwordKey = "<decryptionKey>"

let userInfoToUserRecord (user: UserInfo): ImportUserRecordArgs =
    let record = new ImportUserRecordArgs()
    record.Uid <- user.UserId.ToString()  // GUID to string conversion
    record.Email <- user.Email.ToLower()
    record.PasswordHash <- Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user.Password)
    record.PasswordSalt <- Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user.PasswordSalt) 
    record.DisplayName <- $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"
    record.EmailVerified <- true
    record

let userRecords: List<ImportUserRecordArgs> =  users |> List.map (fun x -> userInfoToUserRecord x)

let userRecordOpptions = UserImportOptions()
let hmac = HmacSha1()
hmac.Key <-  Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwordKey)
userRecordOpptions.Hash <- hmac

//  Up to 1000 users can be imported at once.
let importAuthUsers () =
    async {
        try
            let auth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(mceAPIFirebase)
            let! result = auth.ImportUsersAsync(userRecords, userRecordOpptions) |> Async.AwaitTask
            printfn $"Successfully imported {result.SuccessCount} users"
            printfn $"Failed to import {result.FailureCount} users"
            for error in result.Errors do
                printfn $"Failed to import user at index: {error.Index} due to error: {error.Reason}"
        with
        | ex -> printfn $"Some unrecoverable error occurred: {ex.Message}"
    } |> Async.StartAsTask

importAuthUsers()

I have tried both the validationKey and decryptionKey.
I would be grateful if someone can point me in the right direction.
